# How to add a drop down in HTML?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I currently have the following code :

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" required placeholder="Enter Your First Name">
</div>
```

I wish to add a drop down menu with several options using the 'select input type', but I don't know how to do this.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: OK, so do it. What's the problem?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Comment: I don't understand the down vote? It's a valid question.

Comment: SO is not here to write code for you

Comment: The OP has neither shown an attempt at solving their own issue, nor explained what the issue might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's this simple :

```html
<!-- First name label + input field -->
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" required placeholder="Enter Your First Name">
</div>

<!-- Last name label + input field -->
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" name="last_name" required placeholder="Enter Your Last Name">
</div>

<!-- Gender label + select field -->
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="gender_name">Gender</label>
   <select id="gender_name">
       <option value="male">Male</option>
       <option value="female">Female</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" required placeholder="Enter Your First Name">
   <select id="some_select">
       <option value="value">Value</option>
       <!-- PUT THE REST OF YOUR OPTIONS HERE -->
   </select>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```